# How to remove default button border with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a rounded button like this.

```css
.rock{
height:100px;
width:100px;
border-radius:100px;
border-color:yellow;
border-width:8px;
}
```

```html
<button class="rock" type='button'>Button</button>
```

My question is, how can I remove the weird half-colored thing that shows up on the button border and changes when clicked. I just want the button border to be solid yellow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set [border-style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-style) to `solid`. I think it's `outset` by default, which gives you a more beveled treatment.

```css
.rock {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  border-color: yellow;
  border-width: 8px;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<button class="rock" type='button'>Button</button>
```